# How can I access the copy buffer on the web?

Tags: copy-paste

Wild question here.

Is it possible to access the copy buffer on the web. What I mean is. Can I go into Photoshop. Select a **piece** of a photo. Copy that piece and paste it into some element.

That something would be like a Java applet or Flash or Silverlight or anything. I am just wondering if it is possible and if someone could point me in a direction. Since a few google searches have only found where you can copy files and paste via a Java applet.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.datatransfer/ToClipImg.html

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps look into [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard) about granting Javascript access to the clipboard. Do some testing afterward, to check if you can access the data or not.

Comment: This is for text data (since javascript can't nativly handle binary data). But not the data I'm looking for. Thanks though.